# R compute average increase for a timeseries dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, exploratory-data-analysis

Let' say I have the following dataset.

How can I compute the average increase in times (I don't know a proper word for this)?

Meaning you know like I want to tell the audience, that the `average temperature` in `2021` increased this many times compared to `1980`.

Sample data (`AvgTMean`):

```
structure(list(year = 1980:2021, AvgTMean = c(24.2700686838937, 
23.8852956598276, 25.094446596092, 24.1561175050287, 24.157183605977, 
24.3047482638362, 24.7899738481466, 24.5756232655603, 24.5833086228592, 
24.7344695534483, 25.3094451071121, 25.2100615173707, 24.3651692293534, 
24.5423890611494, 25.2492166633908, 24.7005097837931, 24.2491591827443, 
25.0912281781322, 25.0779264303305, 24.403294248319, 24.4983991453592, 
24.4292324356466, 24.8179824927011, 24.7243948463075, 24.5086534543966, 
24.2818632071983, 24.4567195220259, 24.8402224356034, 24.6574465515086, 
24.5440715673563, 23.482670620977, 24.9979594684914, 24.5452453980747, 
24.9271462811494, 24.7443215819253, 25.8929839790805, 25.1801908261063, 
25.2079308058908, 25.0722425561207, 25.4554644289799, 25.4548979078736, 
25.0756772250287)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-42L))
```

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)

AvgTMean %>% # Stuck...?
```

Comment: Let me try sir.

Comment: So, this gives me a value of  `-0.0151` for `2021`, I was expecting it to be positive since the overall (`42 years`) temperature increase using `lm` is `0.4 C`.

Comment: Sorry it's `0.8 C` overall change actually done by `AvgTMeanYearLM = lm(AvgTMean ~ year, data = AvgTMeanYear)
summary(AvgTMeanYearLM)`

Comment: @akrun, thank you sir, I will give that a try too. I am sorry for not being clear on this. It's just that you know often in `climate reports` you come across statements like for example `compared to the last 100 years the temperature has increased this many times on average`. So, based on my data I don't know how or what's the best way to convey such information to the audience in similar fashion.

Comment: Yes, I am open to ideas sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the slope of the regression line to get the increase per year based on fitting a linear model to the data.

```
fm <- lm(AvgTMean ~ year, DF); fm
## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = AvgTMean ~ year, data = DF)
##
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)         year  
##    -6.93064      0.01582  <-- 0.01582 degree increase per yr

plot(DF)
abline(fm)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes, I have already done this, and I got an increase of `0.8C`  for the `42 year` period.

Comment: No No sorry what I did was `0.01582` rounded to `0.02` so `0.02 *42 = 0.8 C`

Comment: Should I also add some something like the temperature over the 42 year period increase for example twice or thrice (or like an average) as much? I guess I am just overthinking it haha.

Comment: What you report really depends on your purpose.  Note that you can use `confint(fm)` to get 95% confidence interval on the increase per year.  i.e.   (0.004837174, 0.02681282) based on the data in the question.

Comment: Thank you, so what are these two values `0.004837174, 0.02681282` telling me?

Comment: See wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval

Comment: Oh so it means in a `95%` `CI`, the temperature change is between `0.004837174` and `0.02681282` ?

Comment: The confidence interval is PER YEAR.  Carefully read wikipedia if you want the interpretation of what a confidence interval is.  Note that it is not the probability that the temperature lies in that interval.

Comment: Also (1) you can't round 0.01582 to 0.2 and then multiply it by 42 without introducing a large error. Consider the difference between round(0.01582, 2) * 42 = 0.84 vs 0.01582 * 42 = 0.66 . (2) There are 42 years from the beginning of 1980 to the end of 2021 but there are 41 years from the midpoint of 1980 to the midpoint of 2021 (or from the end of 1980 to the end of 2021) so you need to be decide what you want or maybe  you can just report the per year value and avoid the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, that certainly is a big difference. I will go ahead and make these corrections in my white paper. So, without rounding I will do for example `0.01582 * 41 = 0.64862C or 0.65C`.

Answer (score 1):

```
data <- structure(list(year = 1980:2021, AvgTMean = c(24.2700686838937, 
                                          23.8852956598276, 25.094446596092, 24.1561175050287, 24.157183605977, 
                                          24.3047482638362, 24.7899738481466, 24.5756232655603, 24.5833086228592, 
                                          24.7344695534483, 25.3094451071121, 25.2100615173707, 24.3651692293534, 
                                          24.5423890611494, 25.2492166633908, 24.7005097837931, 24.2491591827443, 
                                          25.0912281781322, 25.0779264303305, 24.403294248319, 24.4983991453592, 
                                          24.4292324356466, 24.8179824927011, 24.7243948463075, 24.5086534543966, 
                                          24.2818632071983, 24.4567195220259, 24.8402224356034, 24.6574465515086, 
                                          24.5440715673563, 23.482670620977, 24.9979594684914, 24.5452453980747, 
                                          24.9271462811494, 24.7443215819253, 25.8929839790805, 25.1801908261063, 
                                          25.2079308058908, 25.0722425561207, 25.4554644289799, 25.4548979078736, 
                                          25.0756772250287)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                      -42L)) 




 n <- length(data$AvgTMean) ##n to identify the position of your reference/last year (last value)
 reference <- data$AvgTMean[n]
 increase <- (reference/data$AvgTMean)
```

You will get a numerical vector indicating how much the `AvgTMean` increased in respect to last year/value temperature for each year.